# how to copy properties from one google chrome user to another on OSX

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, google-chrome-extensions, user-profiles, google-chrome-devtools

I'm a big user of chrome (switch person) feature:

[image]

i'm also a heavy user of chrome's custom search engines

[image]

so it's very common for me to have like 100 different search engines for a specific chrome user.. but then i gotta create a new one.. is there a way to migrate these search engines (and other chrome user's settings for that matter) from one user to another?

Comment: What OS is this for ?

Comment: @linuxdev2013 osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## update

in addition to the instructions below.. you must also disable settings sync first.. see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1133530/2341410) answer for more details.

---

turns out it's easy.. user specific data is stored here

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile %/
```

where the profile number corresponds to each profile you have in chrome (you can double check by finding the file *Google Profile Picture* the corresponds to the profile u're looking for..

so suppose you have two profiles
Profile 1 (master)
profiel 2 (slave)

you simply want to copy the file

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile (master)/Web Data
```

to

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile (slave)/Web Data
```

and replace it.

the only side effect is that you'll be logged out of your chrome users.. just log back in and you're golden!

[image]

[image]