# how to mass change chrome custom search engines

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, google-chrome-extensions, user-profiles, google-chrome-devtools

## Background

I use chrome [custom search engines](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) very often (i wrote a post about how to copy search engines from one profile to another [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1056274/how-to-copy-properties-from-one-google-chrome-user-to-another-on-osx/1056306#1056306)).

## Problem

I recently switched from github to gitlab, and so i have like 50 custom search engines that began with something like `github.com/repo_name` that i know what to change to something like `gitlab.com/repo_name`..

I know that the custom search engines are stored inside

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile/Web Data
```

and according to my other post, if i simply copied and pasted that between profiles, things would work fine.. however if i go inside that web data file now (which is an sqlite file) and manually [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807881/766570) the strings, and copy it back.. it simply gets overwritten by the original search engines.. any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]turns out the answer is logical. You see before you try to "game" the system you must understand it first.. when you go to google settings, you can click on `advanced sync settings` and select `choose what to sync` and then uncheck settings.. in that case you leave your google account vulnerable to have it settings overwritten..

after that you can follow the steps of copying `web data` and that's it!